# How to check if sqlite2 is installed?

Tags: php, sqlite2

How can I check if `sqlite2` is installed? Is it relatively easy?

Is it as simple as a 1 line check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with this code:

```
$sqlite = extension_loaded('sqlite');
if ($sqlite)
{
    echo 'SQLITE IS INSTALLED';
}
```

You can also check **which version is installed**:

```
$sqlite2 = extension_loaded('sqlite2');
$sqlite3 = extension_loaded('sqlite3');
if ($sqlite2 || $sqlite3)
{
    if ($sqlite2)
    {
     echo 'SQLITE2 IS INSTALLED';
    }

    if ($sqlite3)
    {
     echo 'SQLITE3 IS INSTALLED';
    }
} else
{
  echo 'SQL IS NOT INSTALLED';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(extension_loaded('sqlite')) {
  [ .... ]
}
```

If the `sqlite` extension is available, then you can proceed using it as you wish.

See also: http://php.net/extension_loaded

Comment: Does this work for version 2 and version 3? I need to load a different file for `sqlite2` and `sqlite3` separately.

Comment: Version 3 should be named `sqlite3` while version 2 is simply `sqlite`